# Term for coordinate noun phrase containing contrasting things

Tags: syntactic-analysis, descriptive-grammar

For a sentence along the lines of "There were celebrations and not-so-celebrations among the people." what would the correct term for a this phrase? I thought it may be a comparison or something along those lines but I am not sure.

Comment: 'a noun phrase containing contrasted elements'

Comment: See also [linguistics.se]

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for "antithesis".

Answer (score 1):

This answer, coincidentally, contains two things:

***dichotomy***:

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dichotomy):
>
>   1. a division
>        into two especially mutually exclusive or contradictory groups or entities
>
>      - the *dichotomy* between theory and practice;
>          *also*: the process or practice of making such a division
>
>        *dichotomy* of the population into two opposed classes
>
>      something with seemingly contradictory qualities
>
> [Oxford English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/dichotomy):
>
>   A division or contrast between two things
>     that are or are represented as being opposed or entirely different.
>   *‘a rigid dichotomy between science and mysticism’*
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=dichotomy):
>
>   A division into two contrasting parts or categories:
>     the dichotomy between rural and urban communities
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dichotomy):
>
>   If there is a dichotomy between two things,
>     there is a very great difference or opposition between them.

***juxtaposition***:

> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/juxtaposition):
>
>   the act or an instance of placing two or more things side by side
>     often to compare or contrast or to create an interesting effect
>   - an unusual juxtaposition of colors;
>       *also*: the state of being so placed
>
>     contrasting shapes placed in juxtaposition to each other
>
> [Oxford English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/juxtaposition):
>
>   The fact of two things being seen or placed close together
>     with contrasting effect.
>   *‘the juxtaposition of these two images’*
>
> [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=juxtaposition):
>
>   The act or an instance of juxtaposing
>     or the state of being juxtaposed.
>       [*juxtapose*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=juxtapose)
>       :
>         To place side by side, especially
>           for comparison or contrast.
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/juxtaposition):
>
>   The juxtaposition of two contrasting objects, images, or ideas
>     is the fact that they are placed together or described together,
>     so that the differences between them are emphasized.